# How can I access the same homepage from different menus?

Tags: menu, joomla

I have a menu item "Home" in my main menu AND in my top menu. When I click on the "Home" in the top menu, I would like it to direct me to the "Home" referenced in the main menu. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

Have one of the menu items as the default menu item. For the other menu item choose the menu type to be Alias (Menu Link) and choose the menu item that is the default menu item.

(Thank you user imanickam on forum.joomla.org, url: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=428&t=456584&p=1912878#p1912878)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is something special in Joomla to configure this, but href="/home.html" will always to the same place.  Relative links do not work this way however, so from

/folder1/ a link to "home.html" would not go to the same place as:

/folder2/ which contains a page with a link to "home.html"

adding the preceeding slash makes it relative to the site rather than to the current folder.

Hope this helps, if not let me know what I could do to point you in a better direction.